# Having interpreting this line in Python , where a conditional comes after a range specification.

Tags: python

I having trouble interpreting `indexes =[ s.index(l) for l in letters if s.count(l) == 1]` from the code below

```
class Solution:
    def firstUniqChar(self, s):
        """
        :type s: str
        :rtype: int
        """
        letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
        indexes =[ s.index(l) for l in letters if s.count(l) == 1]
        return min(indexes) if len(indexes) > 0 else -1
```

It looks like it's going through string s and if a letter from letts is in the string s, it records where that index position is. Then it returns only indexes if the count for that index is equel to 1. But I tried to run the code without the conditional in that line

`indexes =[ s.index(l) for l in letters ]`

and it returns an error

'ValueError: substring not found'

Here is what I use to instatiate and run the function

```
sol = Solution()
sol.firstUniqChar('loveleetcode')
```

Comment: Ugh, bad code..

Comment: Hint: What happens when you try to find the index in `s` of a letter that `s` doesn't contain?

Comment: BTW, that's not the worst way to find the 1st unique char in a string, but it's pretty close. ;)

Comment: @PM2Ring That's a good question then The OP has to do find and do an if statement to check if it is not `-1`

Comment: @U9-Forward Yes, you can use `.find` instead of `.index` to avoid raising an exception. Or you could catch the exception. But for this task there's no need to do that. Instead, you use a more efficient algorithm that doesn't test on letters that aren't even in the string. And you stop as soon as you find the 1st unique char. Of course, it's possible that the actual task is to find the index of the 1st unique lowercase ASCII letter; the OP should clarify that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to rewrite the hard to understand piece in a bit different way, this:

```
indexes =[ s.index(l) for l in letters if s.count(l) == 1]
```

becomes this (I've also replaced hard to read lowercase 'l' with 'c' (as in 'character'):

```
indexes = []
for c in letters :
    if s.count(c) == 1 :    # check if 's' contains a unique 'c'
        indexes.append( s.index(c) )
```

So, you see, if you remove `if s.count(c) == 1` conditional, it will try to find in `s` ALL possible lowercase letters, not only those that are included in `s` only once, and give you the exception once the letter is not found.

Answer (score 0):

`str.index(sub)` will throw an exception if `sub` does not exist in `str`, so if you don't specify a search condition, then the `s.index(l)` will run into the `ValueError` exception. I guess you need to change your way.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your goal is to find the first unique character in a single string you can do the following: (You don't actually have to iterate over the whole alphabet)

```
class Solution:
    def firstUniqChar(self, s):
        """
        :type s: str
        """
        assert isinstance(s,str), "Please insert a valid string"
        s=s.lower()

        counter = {}
        for key in s:
             counts = s.count(key)
             if counts == 1 and key.isAlpha():
                 counter[key] = counts

     return min(counter, key=counter.get) if len(counter) > 0 else -1

sol = Solution()
print(sol.firstUniqChar('toobad'))

>t
```

this will return the first character appearing uniquely in the string itself. If you want the first alphabet letter appearing uniquely you do (there are ways of not iterating I just did like because probably is not what you want):

```
class Solution:
    def firstUniqChar(self, s):
        """
        :type s: str
        """
        assert isinstance(s,str), "Please insert a valid string"
        s=s.lower()

        counter = {}
        for key in 'abc......':
             counts = s.count(key)
             if counts == 1:
                 counter[key] = counts

     return min(counter, key=counter.get) if len(counter) > 0 else -1

sol = Solution()
print(sol.firstUniqChar('toobad'))

>a
```

Comment: you're supposed to return an index, not a character itself

Comment: Of the reference alphabet or string itself?

Comment: `s.index(l)` does not seem like a reference alphabet

Comment: I meant to ask if the OP wants the index of 't' or 'a' in the examples I gave, cause I thought there was a difference but actually s.find(min(counter, key=counter.get)) works both ways. Cheers.